# GRID COLUMNS atk4 agiletoolkit

Tags: grid, atk4, agiletoolkit

Hi I am trying to get some referenced data from another table,

Data structure:

Table PartDetail
-id
-OperationTypeID(foreign key)
-DateAdded

Table OperationType
-id
-Description

I am trying something like this:

`$crud = $this->add('MVCGrid', array('allow_edit'=>false));`
`$crud->setModel('Model_PartDetail',array('DateAdded'));`

But then I want to see the "description" from table OperationType, because on my PartDetail model I declare my relationship like this:

`$this->hasOne('OperationType','OperationTypeID','Description')
        ->mandatory(true)

        ->caption('Operation Type');`

for example in this case I want to see the description from the table OperationType

I tried:
`$crud->setModel('Model_PartDetail',array('DateAdded','OperationType'));`

but is not working, only works with:
`$crud->setModel('Model_PartDetail',array('DateAdded','OperationTypeID'));`

but I get only the ID number, not the description.

How this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solved it.

on the model you need to redefine it as

```
$ref = $this->add('Field_Reference', 'OperationTypeID');
$ref->dereferenced_field='OperationTypeDescription';

$m = $this->add('Model_OperationType');
$m->addField('D'); // <-- actually seems that this line is not working

$ref->setModel($m, 'Description');
```

And then in the page you can actually added as OperationTypeDescription:

```
$crud->setModel('Model_PartDetail', array('DateAdded', 'OperationTypeDescription'));
```

Comment: There should be easier solution.